# InlfuxDB TOP function poor performances

Tags: influxdb

I'm using InfluxDB and I'm trying to query values in it with TOP() function.

Here is an exemple of request :

`SELECT TOP("duration", 2) AS "top_duration" FROM "range" WHERE "time" > '2017-11-23T15:23:32.243Z' AND "contract" = 'A0000544' AND "type" = 'PRESENCE' AND "room" = '3908' AND "endTime" < 80785557 AND "startTime" > 28630649`

In the measurement `contract`, `type` and `room` are tags, `duration`, `startTime` and `endTime` are fields.

I have around 37 866 326 points in range, but only 78 962 for contract 'A0000544' and 10 487 for room '3908'

This request takes several seconds and I'm trying to reduce the processing time.

I tried to create another measurement to reduce my sample and keeping only biggest "duration".

I kept only 4 066 728 points but the processing time was the same.

When I keep only the point about the contract in the measurement the request take around 300ms.

I don't understand why I have so much execution time difference with empty database and in the other hand no difference with the filtered measurement.

Am I missing something? Is there any other possible optimisations?

Answer (score 0):

That is just an assumption, but maybe having *filtering by filed* rather then by tags alone + *having 3 fields in a single measurement* is a performance killer. Field are not indexed, so filtering by fields requires a full table scan). Besides, multiple fields per data point create multiple index entries.

I am not sure of the solution... Probably, InfluxDB was not designed for such a complex table schema.